# No connection when mixing cat5e and cat6?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

My home network looks like this:

```
internet => rg6 => modem => cat6 => cat5e => router => ...

router => cat5e => devices (OK)
       => cat5e => cat6 => switch => cat5e => devices (OK)
                           switch => **cat5e** => cat6 => cat5e => devices (BOOM)
```

The reason for mixing cat6 and cat5e is because the cat6 cables go through the walls and are terminated in a keystone, which I then connect cat5e cables to. For the last row at the top figure, my macOS laptops show self assigned IP addresses and cannot connect to the internet. Is there something I'm missing? My switch is a Netgear JGS524 if that matters.

EDIT: If I switch the **cat5e** above to another cat6, I can get internet on my macOS laptop, but the switch is showing my speeds as 100M instead of 1GB?

Comment: The salient information that you left out are: which cables are pre- made, which cables were terminated by you, and did you "pull" these cables through the walls?

Comment: Apologies. The cat6's are all terminated/pulled by the previous owners. the cat5es are all patch cables. If I had to guess, something is wrong with that cat6 cable in the last row of my figure...I guess I have to take a look at the keystone jack on both ends?

Comment: Get a cable tester and test that all preterminated cables are properly terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I switch the cat5e above to another cat6, I can get internet on my macOS laptop, but the switch is showing my speeds as 100M instead of 1GB?

Something in the whole chain is degrading the signal quality so much that your particular cat6 cable works, while your particular cat5e cable doesn't. (One reason could be that your particular cat5e cable is faulty).

Check the whole chain for bad contacts, bent cables etc. Check that the connections are correct (match colors). Having an ethernet cable tester helps.

Comment: I tried to redo the keystone jacks for the cat6 but it still didn't work. I pulled out the entire cable but couldn't really see any obvious bents or defects. Ended up just replacing it with a long cat5e and everything is great now. Thanks!